# Angular unit test a service return Promise Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, promise, jasmine

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/unit-testing-an-angularjs-factory-method-returning-a-promise) to make unit test for a service that return a`Promise` but could not get it worked.

My service returns a `Promise` that will retrives `HTML5` geolocation.

```
app.factory('getGeo', function() { 
     return function(){
         return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
          });        
       }
      var options = {
         enableHighAccuracy: true,
         timeout: 5000,
          maximumAge: 0
          };         
});
```

And my controller has a function that resolve the `Promise` to set some states in the app.

```
getGeo().then((position) => {
          //perform logic when geo is received
          $scope.weatherInfo.la = position.coords.latitude;//new properties
          $scope.weatherInfo.lo = position.coords.longitude;//new properties
          $scope.weatherInfo.url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${$scope.weatherInfo.la}&lon=${$scope.weatherInfo.lo}&appid=0d00180d180f48b832ffe7d9179d40c4`;
        })
```

And my test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _getGeo_){
   $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
   $getGeo = _getGeo_;
 }));

describe('getGeo method', function() {
  it('getGeo should return a promise', function() {
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var position = {coords:{coords:{latitude:'1',latitude:'3'}}};
    $getGeo().then(function(position) {
    expect($scope.weatherInfo.url).not.toBeNull();
    done();
   });
   $scope.$digest();                
 });
});
```

I got this `SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS getGeo should return a promise`. Seems the code inside the mock service never gets called. But if I move out the `expect($scope.weatherInfo.url).not.toBeNull()` and put it under `$scope.$digest()` I'd get a `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` error.

Answer (score 1):

1. `var position = {coords:{coords:{latitude:'1',latitude:'3'}}};
       $getGeo().then(function(position) {
       expect($scope.weatherInfo.url).not.toBeNull();
   }`

Variable in callback - it is the data which promise will return. It is not your `var position = {coords:{coords:{latitude:'1',latitude:'3'}}};`

2. I think you shouldn't call the factory in the test. The factory will call constructor only one time when you inject its first.
   So you just need to make next

   `$getGeo.then(function(position) {...})`
3. Your factory takes data from outside `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. So you need to make stub for it.

   `spyOn(navigator.geolocation, 'getCurrentPosition').andReturn(/* here is the data which you expected */)`

It is hard to show you the full example. However, I tried to describe critical things.

Comment: thanks @NechiK for the answer, I am not too sure what this statement means  --- So you just need to make next `$getGeo.then(function(position) {...})`. Does it mean I need to omit this code because I dont want to call the factory?

Comment: `var position = {coords:{coords:{latitude:'1',latitude:'3'}}};
 spyOn(navigator.geolocation, 'getCurrentPosition').and.returnValue(position);
 $getGeo()` this does not work either.

Comment: I think you shouldn't call the factory function. It will initialize automatically.
I would create the example of code which you provided, but unfortunately, I very busy now.
I will try to do it in 1 day. And probably I will provide solution to you